# Spring data + Spring Boot: returning 200 if resource was updated or 201 if resource was created

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I implemented an update endpoint for a user.

I would like to know how to return 201 status when user is created and 200 if user was just updated using the Spring framework features as much as possible (not custom things).

I have this UserController:

```
@RequestMapping("users")
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  ...

  @PutMapping
  public UserDTO update(@RequestBody User user) {
    User updated = userService.update(user);
    return updated;
  }
}
```

This UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  ...

  public User update(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

And this UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
}
```

I know that exists Spring Data Rest that directly exposes the resources but is not the answer I'm looking for (doesn't meet my needs since I really need the service and repository layers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ResponseEntity<T>`, which allows you to specify a status.

```java
@PutMapping
  public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> update(@RequestBody User user) {
    User updated = userService.update(user);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(updated);
  }
```

More about this approach in this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity).